# Is there a quick way to see all door permissions?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

So I had to override some of the default permissions on some of the doors in my colony. Life goes on, and all of a sudden I get notified about some character not being able to access food, or something similar... and then I remember! "Damn, I changed the door permissions!" And then I need to go through *all* the damned doors, to make sure the permissions I set still all make sense — but to do so, I need to click through all of the doors, and check which have overrides, and which don't.

Is there a way to get an overview of all the doors? Or to at least see just which ones have overrides? Or, ideally, to quickly cycle between all the doors?

Comment: So far, there is no _quick way_ to see all premissinons, maybe in later updates

Answer (score 2):

You can't so far, but you can cycle through duplicants (you accomplish this by clicking the stress percentage stat of the colony) and see all their possible paths by clicking in the dupe's interface button "Show Navigation". Zoom further out with Alt+S to have a broader picture.